# Update field in state array object

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

I am building a simple TODO app in React. I have a `todos` array in the state, and each `todo` has a flag `completed`. When an item is clicked, I want to toggle the `completed` flag of that `todo`. Here's what I've done so far:

**Todos.js**

```
class Todos extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [
          { id:0, title:"Title 0", completed:false },
          { id:1, title:"Title 1", completed:true }
         ]
    };
    this.onTodoClicked = this.onTodoClicked.bind(this);
  }

  onTodoClicked(id) {
    console.log(id + " clicked");
    this.setState(prevState => {
      todos: prevState.todos.map((item, index) => {
        return index !== id ? item : { ...item, completed: !item.completed };
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.todos.map((todoItem, key) => (
          <Todo id={key} key={key} todo={todoItem}
            todoClicked={this.onTodoClicked} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Todo.js** is just a simple component (yes, it could be functional as well)

```
class Todo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.props.todoClicked(this.props.id)}>
        {this.props.todo.title}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In **Todos.js** the function `onTodoClicked` is called and it prints out the correct id, but nothing else changes in the state (I inspected the clicked object both with React dev tools and console.log's). The clicked item doesn't change its `completed` flag. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: indices start from `0` and your `id` start from `1`

Comment: @marzelin I changed it now, thanks. Actually, this is just an example. In the real app I'm fetching the data from jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, but I didn't want to pollute this.

Comment: `id={key}` should be `id={todoItem.id}`

Comment: you shouldn't pass `id` to `Todo` anyway since you pass the whole `todoItem`. That's redundant

Comment: @marzelin I changed it to `id={todoItem.id}` and removed the redundant id prop, but still doesn't work.

Comment: you're missing parens after `prevState =>`

Comment: @marzelin That was it. Damn parenthesis... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it should look:

```js
class Todos extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [
          { id:0, title:"Title 0", completed:false },
          { id:1, title:"Title 1", completed:true }
         ]
    };
    this.onTodoClicked = this.onTodoClicked.bind(this);
  }

  onTodoClicked(id) {
    console.log(id + " clicked");
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      todos: prevState.todos.map((item, index) => {
        return item.id !== id ? item : { ...item, completed: !item.completed };
      })
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.todos.map((todoItem, key) => (
          <Todo key={key} todo={todoItem}
            todoClicked={this.onTodoClicked} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Todo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.props.todoClicked(this.props.todo.id)}>
        {this.props.todo.title} {this.props.todo.completed && "completed"}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todos/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I was missing parenthesis after `prevState =>`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to rely on the `id`, instead of the `index`:

```
return item.id !== id ? item : { ...item, completed: !item.completed };
```

Also for `Todo` id you should pass the id, not the key (`id={key}`) (or just past the whole todoItem only):

```
id={todoItem.id}
```

For `Todo` key pass the `id` too, because passing the same `key` index, your `Todo` item may not be rerendered.

And finally, you're missing the parenthesis after `prevState => ({`

---

```js
class Todo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.props.todoClicked(this.props.todo.id)}>
        {this.props.todo.title} - {this.props.todo.completed.toString()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Todos extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [
          { id:0, title:"Title 0", completed:false },
          { id:1, title:"Title 1", completed:true }
         ]
    };
    this.onTodoClicked = this.onTodoClicked.bind(this);
  }

  onTodoClicked(id) {
    console.log(id);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      todos: prevState.todos.map((item, index) => {
        return item.id !== id ? item : { ...item, completed: !item.completed };
      })
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.todos.map((todoItem, key) => (
          <Todo key={todoItem.id} todo={todoItem}
            todoClicked={this.onTodoClicked} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todos />, document.querySelector("#container"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Updated, please check it :)

Comment: Please try the last suggestion too (about the key).

Comment: Did you change `onTodoClicked` to rely on `id`, instead of `index`?

Comment: I've added a working example, with your code. Please follow it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to changes in **onTodoClicked** Function.it will works.

```
onTodoClicked(id) {
        console.log(id + " clicked");
        this.state.todos[id].completed = !this.state.todos[id].completed;
        this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos });
        console.log("state,", this.state.todos);
      }
```

This is link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yxxksp?file=index.js

Comment: You shouldn't modify the State, because of immutable React's state principles. `this.state.todos[id].completed = !this.state.todos[id].completed;`

Comment: I agree with @JordanEnev, I think that the right way is to use setState and prevState

Comment: state is update when click on item, you can see demo link.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could do in Todo.js

```
class Todo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div onClick={() => this.props.todoClicked(this.props.todo.id)}>
       {this.props.todo.title}
     </div>
  );
 }
}
```

And in onTodoClicked function, you could do something like this.

```
onTodoClicked(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      todos: prevState.todos.map((item) => {
       return item.id !== id ? item : { ...item, completed: !item.completed };
     });
   });
  }
```

I hope this will help you.